# redirect future visits based on link selected

Tags: php, cookies

I'm building a website for a church that has three different locations. The home page has some brief information and then each campus listed. I'd like to store what location the user selects and then redirect them to that location on future visits.

For example - they visit church.com and on the home page they select location2 (church.com/location2)

Next time they enter church.com in their browser, they're automatically redirected to church.com/location2

Thanks!

Comment: I guess [Cookies](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) are what you are looking for.

Comment: Is this a good idea? What if someone just happened to be browsing one church's page, but ultimately wanted to go to another one? Or moved house and needed to access one of the other two? If you still want to do this, search for "JavaScript persistent storage"

Comment: There is a quick and easy way to change locations across all the locations' pages

Answer (score 2):

you can store the value in a [cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)...

when the user visits i.e. location 2:

```
<?php
    $location = 2;
    // setcookie(name, value, expirationTime);
    setcookie("location", $location, time() + 2592000); // expiration time of one month
?>
```

In the beginning of your script you have to check whether the "location" cookie is already set. If yes -> redirect to the appropriate page

```
<?php
    $location = $_COOKIE["location"];
    if(isset($location))
    {
        header("location: /location".$location);
    }
?>
```

#### WordPress solution

As I mentioned in the comments, I am no WordPress pro. However, the following solution works for me. Please don't forget to set your cookies before anything is outputted by a script. I placed the following lines in the template's header.php

```
// get postname (I used postname in 'Permalink Settings')
$location = get_query_var('name');

// if user is on startpage + was not redirected yet -> redirect
// if you don't set the userRedirected cookie, the user is not 
// able to visit the startpage anymore to chose a location
if($location == "" && isset($_COOKIE["location"]) && !$_COOKIE["userRedirected"])
{
    // path "/" makes the cookie available on the whole domain
    setcookie("userRedirected", true, null, "/"); // duration: session
    header("location: ".$_COOKIE["location"]); // redirect
}

if($location == "location-1")
{
    // set location cookie 1
    setcookie("location", "location-1", time() + 2592000, "/");
}
else if($location == "location-2")
{
    // set location cookie 2
    setcookie("location", "location-2", time() + 2592000, "/");
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: That second bit would go on the homepage, correct? @lionheart98

Comment: exactly! the second code snippet just loads the cookie, stores its content in `$location` and redirects the user to the corresponding page if the variable is set.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. However, I think I hurt myself when I failed to mention that this is a dynamic site running a WordPress. Any suggestions how to handle that?

Comment: I am really sorry, but unfortunately, I don't have much experience with WordPress. But if I look at some examples on the web, it seems to be pretty similar to the solution I provided. [example](http://wptheming.com/2011/04/set-a-cookie-in-wordpress/)

Comment: @tstrebeck please check my updated answer. Now with WordPress example.